# Scala + Android Newbie

Tags: android, scala, sbt

I am trying to use the scala-andriod plugin and I am having a problem running and configuring AVD's.  Im getting following errors from sbt

> android:emulator-start NexusOne
>   [success] Total time: 0 s, completed Nov 18, 2011 7:07:53 PM
>   emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!

I have followed the direction on creating an avd but for some reason when I run the avd from sbt and android SDK manager I get that error.

Background:
I used homebrew to install the sdk
The .android folder containing the AVDs is in the default location mac home directory

Comment: maven or sbt? which environment variable did you set? ANDROID_HOME, ANDROID_SDK_HOME, ...

Comment: I tried to set all 3. But currently I have .bashrc set to export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/r13

Answer (score 5):

On the Android SDK manager, install/reinstall "ARM EABI v7a System Image" and then create a new AVD.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it helps some people:

When running the "Android Virtual Device Manager". Clicking the Detail button, the AVD shows the AVD location on your system. Going to this directory will show you a config.ini file.

I changed the image.sysdir.1 value to something other in that particular file.

After going back to the AVD manager, it shows the virtual device with a repair option.
Clicking the repair button wields something in the logs like:

```
[SDK Manager] Updated 'image.sysdir.1' with value 'add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-16/images/armeabi-v7a/'
[SDK Manager] Updated 'image.sysdir.2' with value 'system-images/android-16/armeabi-v7a/'
```

The thing to I noticed it added a image.sysdir.2 value. After this repair I can start the AVD without a missing kernel message.

Comment: Hi, the path I got from the details window is not a real path it seems, it says /myrootfolder/.android/... but I don't have a folder that is labeled .android. Do you know another way to find this folder? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is purely an error on the side of Android's emulator -- it has nothing to do with Scala, or SBT.  You can find the text of the error in [this code](http://android.yongbok.net/repository/external/qemu/android/main.c), if you like.

So, I don't know what directions you followed when you created the AVD, but the AVD is malformed.  Create a new one by running the `android` tool in the tools/ directory of the Android SDK, and then finding `Manage AVDs...` in the `Tools` menu.

(And to save you some time: after you have a good AVD, use `android:package-debug` to build an `.apk`, and `android:install-emulator` to move it into the emulator.  You can do this while the emulator's running.)