# Android emulator error:missing kernel file

Tags: android, android-emulator

```
emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!
```

- I have updated version of sdk and adt.
- I have also installed The "*ARM EABI v7a System Image*".
- I just build the Android ActionBarSherlock and SlidingMenu library.
- I have also updated my eclipse.

Any idea where is the problem?

Comment: try creating a new emulator. may be the config file of current one got corrupt

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Update your SDK. Do check again if the **ARM EZBI v&a system Image** is installed correctly. If it not installed. you will see it in the Android Sdk Manager. 
Also check whether your SDK path and java path is set properly. It may very well be the case of file not found. check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10775330/2021499)  it may help.

Comment: Also make sure, you delete the existing avd instance and recreate it after installing to solve this problem

Comment: I have done all the things in Android Studio , But the error is still same emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!! Can you please help me to resolve previously its working fine is this Android Studio version issue or else.

Comment: I dont have experience with Android Studio so cant really answer your question here. but as far as i know there are some specific changes required for running emulators on Android Studio. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717064/android-emulator-in-android-studio-doesnt-start 
check if this link has the solution to your problem.

Comment: If you are getting this error while trying to create an emulator for **Android 10+ or Android 11**, make sure that you have updated your emulator from Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools