# Android emulator error, with ionic

Tags: android, ubuntu, ionic-framework

Inspired from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712605/emulator-error-this-avds-configuration-is-missing-a-kernel-file) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540642/android-emulator-errormissing-kernel-file), I've tried to configure the android emulator on Ubuntu 14.04 to emulate my ionic app with the command `ionic emulate android`.
But I get this error : `emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!`

I've installed rev 19 of the android SDK : [image]
The `"ARM EABI v7a System Image"` is installed.

I don't how to get the window "Edit Android Virtual Device AVD".

`$ echo $JAVA_HOME` gives
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

I have this in my ~/.bashrc

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/louisro/android-sdk-linux/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/louisro/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Can you help me figure out what's wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have no AVD created, like I did, you'll get a message like this:

```
WARNING : no emulator specified, defaulting to Android_5_1
Waiting for emulator...
emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!
```

My issue was resolved simply by creating an AVD:

```
android list targets
```

Pick your target API id, in my case it was 11 for Android 4.4.2 (API 19), then create an AVD with the target id:

```
android create avd -n android_4_4_2 -t 11  

ionic emulate android
```

Comment: thanks. I did what you recommend and I get a new error : `WARNING : no emulator specified, defaulting to android_4_4_2
Waiting for emulator...
qemu: could not load initrd ''
`

Comment: now I tried to choose the other --abi option when creating avd....and I get this `WARNING : no emulator specified, defaulting to android_4_4_2
Waiting for emulator...
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure KVM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: KVM is not installed on this machine (/dev/kvm is missing).
`

Comment: I get errors from the protocol from this page : `virsh -c qemu:///system list
error : impossible to connect to hypervisor
error : Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': Permission not granted`