# No emulator image found while creating a mobile chrome app for android

Tags: android, google-chrome, cordova, android-emulator, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to develop a mobile chrome app.

Here are the steps I followed:

- Install JDK 7
- Install node
- Install cca
- Install ant
- Install android-sdk
- Create a basic "hello-world" desktop chrome app
- `cd` to hello-world and run `cca create mobile-hello-world`
- `cd` to `mobile-hello-world` and run cca run android

Here is the error message I get:

```
ERROR : No emulator images (avds) found, if you would like to create an
 avd follow the instructions provided here:
 http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html
 Or run 'android create avd --name <name> --target <targetID>'
 in on the command line.
```

Isn't cca supposed to take care of creating an emulator image for me?

I don't see any instructions in mobile chrome app documentation for this. What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried to follow the instructions?

Comment: @Xan, yes. The steps I tried are the same as in the instructions.

Comment: And by that I mean instructions in the error message

Comment: @Xan, yes, I did. It works, but the chrome app that gets launched in the emulator just terminates unexpectedly with an "unfortunately calculator has stopped" kind of message. I tried with several genuine supposed-to-work apps officially written by Google. Also I think there was no need to start the emulator image myself. cca was supposed to do it I think.

Comment: Sorry I missed this earlier.  Given that you have created the image now, I'm assuming your new error is unrelated to the description of this question.  Have you resolved the issue?  May you describe the problem?

Comment: @mmocny, no I haven't resolved this. That is all that happens. It installs the apk into the emulator and then I see a dialog in the emulator that says: "unfortunately calculator has stopped".

Comment: May you run "adb logcat" and then try to run the application to see if you get some stack dumps?  This is unexpected and is the first time report.  If you don't mind [filing an issue with us](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/issues), then we can try to help resolve it.  Would be best to start from the beginning to make sure your environment and emulator are set up right -- have you tried on a real device?

Comment: [Similar link with more possible solution options][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712605/emulator-error-this-avds-configuration-is-missing-a-kernel-file

Answer (score 4):

Using the GUI to create a target image helps for point and clickers like me! Run `android avd` to create as many images you need.

---

You'll need to have the SDK installed first, of course; the steps 2 & 3 from the following worked for me:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

These instructions are for 2.8, but worked for me using Cordova 3.5

Run `android` from the commandline to open the SDK manager, and update required components.

Answer (score 1):

Open Android SDK Manager and be sure that ARM EABI v7a System Image is installed.