# emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I am getting the error that emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!.The screenshot is given below[image]

Here is the screenshot regarding the installation details.

[image]

I am using android studio.I have already installed  ARM EABI v 7a System Image.The minimum API version i am using is API14(Android 4.0).Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712605/emulator-error-this-avds-configuration-is-missing-a-kernel-file have u checked this

Comment: yeah i already installed ARM EABI v 7a System Image.