# This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!! Android Studio 1.0.2 OOB

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

Please don't bother with [Emulator error: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712605/emulator-error-this-avds-configuration-is-missing-a-kernel-file) which is almost 3 years old. While the SDK tools are somewhat hidden away in A.S. I have enough experience of them to know that I have the right components to launch an emulator. In theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't answer the original question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404549/this-avds-configuration-is-missing-a-kernel-file, as it was marked as a duplicate so I split my answer into a Q and A:

I've 2 other Android SDK's installed and my environment variables had previously pointed to one:

`ANDROID_SDK
C:\Android\android-sdk
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
C:\Android\android-sdk`

I tried deleting these and creating a new AVD to the same effect. My %PATH% variable was mercifully free of the Android SDK.

What worked for me was restarting the AVD. I'll need to restart Android Studio if I want to see that working too, eventually.