# Unable to run application in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have just switched from Eclipse to Android Studio but now i am getting problem i am not able ti run my application when i am runing it i am getting the error :

```
C:\Users\ga\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none
emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!
emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined
```

Why i am getting this error how can we fix this issue.So that i can run my application .
[image: MINSDK]

I have done all those changes but i am facing the same issue as well as design part of the xml is not visible to me 
[image: DESIGN SECTION]

So these are the issue i am facing please help me fix this
My XML file is :

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".HomePage">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

See for `ARM EABI v7a System Image` i have already installed that 
[image]

Comment: i have done this still i am getting the same error

Comment: i faced the same issue but i haven't got any solution so i moved again to eclipse

Comment: Rendering problem is different and AVD configuration error is different. Rendering problem occurs when you are use a precompiled library in your UI xml which is really annoying but not a bug. If you are facing issues with your AVD, you can use GenyMotion which is free for personal use and very fast as compared to inbuilt AVD.

Comment: @RohanKandwal i have posted my xml also will suggest what needs to be changed in this

Comment: Your xml is fine, but you need to change your theme or API level, as suggested by @AmritPalSingh below.

Comment: the second issue is still @RohanKandwal see in the edit i have posted the image of SDK Manger i have installed that ARM EABI v7a System Image

Comment: @Gaurav Please see this answer and check if it resolves your issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/10101698/1979347. Also, I would recommend you to use GenyMotion which is much better and very fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **design** xml part switch your API level from **22** to API **21** (change it from small android icon at the top of your xml file),

> OR

Go to **res/value/styles.xml** and change your **AppTheme** from

`Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`
to

`Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

[See Reference Link here for design rendering exception.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29062658/rendering-problems-in-android-studio-v-1-1-0/29964412#29964412)

For your initial **emulator error**

`C:\Users\ga\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none
emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!
emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined`

Refer this link -

1 - [Reference link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712605/emulator-error-this-avds-configuration-is-missing-a-kernel-file/10101698#10101698)

2 - [Reference link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28864785/cannot-run-emulator-in-android-studio)

Comment: @AmritPalSingh i have checked both the link before posting but this was not helping to me now i am trying to use genymotion.com

Comment: @Gaurav - I haven't faced these problem will update my answer if I get any solution.