# Android AVD for Jelly Bean and Google APIs --

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I tried to get an Android AVD working for Jelly Bean (API-16) and Google APIs (I included both in the platform definition). When running the AVD I would get the following error.

> $ emulator -avd Nexus_7_API_16_With_Google_APIs
>
> emulator: ERROR: This
> AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!! emulator: ERROR:
> ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is defined (C:\data\applications\Android\Sdk) but
> cannot find kernel file in
> C:\data\applications\Android\Sdk\system-images\ sub directories

I've read through all the similar instances I could find on Stackoverflow and other sites, but none seemed pertinent to my situation.

Unlike most configuration files, the ones used for Jelly Bean and Google API appear to be located in
add-ons rather than in system-image. E.g.:

> $ cd $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd/Nexus_7_API_16_With_Google_APIs.avd/config.ini
>
> $ grep image config.ini
>
> image.sysdir.1=add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-16\images\armeabi-v7a

In fact, "system-image" appears to be hardcoded into the emulator (although it is possible there is a path around that -- see [Cannot run emulator in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28864785/cannot-run-emulator-in-android-studio)).

This looks very much like a bug to me.

Advice???

Thanks,
Barry

Comment: Facing the same issue for 4.2 ARM with Google APIs