# How to run Android 2.3.3 Emulator with Android Studio v2?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

The problem is that in the latest Android Studio, ARM system images for Android 2.3.3 (API 10) is no longer available for download from the SDK Manager. Instead [there is an option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ8jW.jpg) called **Google APIs**, which downloads all files not in the `Android\sdk\system-images` folder, but in the `Android\sdk\add-ons` folder. Under that folder I'm indeed able to find `system.img` and other files, so in theory I should be good to go. But in practice, when I try to run created AVD for Android 2.3.3 I get [this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0cgB.jpg):

> Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
>
> Output:
>
> emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!
>
> emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined

When I set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT path variable it changes the error message to this:

> Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
>
> Output:
>
> emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!
>
> emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is defined
>   (c:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android\sdk) but cannot find kernel file
>   in c:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images\ sub
>   directories

but still no result. It seems that it looking in the wrong directory. Please help. How can I get rid of that error and run that emulator? And what is the difference between `system-images` and `add-ons` folders in the android sdk? Why images from the first one I'm able to run without any trouble and the second one gets me an error?

Searched the web and stackoverflow for similar questions didn't find any correct answer.

***Note:*** Do NOT suggest to download Intel x86 Atom Image - it's useless for me, because I have AMD processor. Do NOT suggest Genymotion, that is not the point of this question.

Comment: In order to run such an old emulator you may need to install a complete old environment when the tooling was still using Eclipse (although you really just need the compatible SDK/Platform tools). Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043522/where-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-the-android-sdk and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710107/where-can-i-find-older-versions-of-eclipse-adt

Comment: I have answered this in another post. You can see it here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38221061/1251535

Answer (score 0):

At first launch SDK manager using link in studio "Launch standalone sdk manager" below the list of sdk platforms, or manually from your sdk folder (path-to-sdk\sdk\SDK Manager.exe).

Make sure that you have installed SDK platform for Android 2.3.3;
ARM system image for Android 2.3.3 (API 10) is not accessible separately, because before Android 4.0, the ARM emulator image is distributed as a part of "SDK Platform" download.
To see other downloads for old platforms, check "Obsolete" checkbox in SDK manager.

As I know, image must appear in "...\sdk\platforms\android-10\" folder

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exact problem and it was solved by specifying the kernel file name as a separate parameter to the command line emulator tool, as given below.

```
emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_25_2_ARM -kernel C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-25\google_apis\arm64-v8a\kernel-qemu
```

Even though it complained that the emulator is out of date, the above command worked like a charm.

Answer (score -2):

As alternative way you can try [GenyMotion Emulator](https://www.genymotion.com/)