# Android SDK Emulator Error: Broken AVD system path

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, archlinux

I am on an Arch Linux x86_64 bit system, 4 Cores, Intel i5 processor and 4 GB RAM.

I've been trying to run Android Emulator from the command line by doing `$ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator -avd "Nexus_5_API_26"`, but I'm getting the following error:

`PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [/home/cocoa/Downloads/SDK/]!`

[Here](https://pastebin.com/9MYXkZV5) are the contents of that directory. I've tried the following post:

[PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645178/panic-broken-avd-system-path-check-your-android-sdk-root-value)

Doesn't work. Thank you in advnace for replying

Answer (score -1):

You can try using this:

```
cd $HOME/Android/Sdk/emulator; ./emulator -use-system-libs -avd Nexus_5_API_26 -netdelay none -netspeed full
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the exact solution

`ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` path variable should point to the folder, which looks like below. 
[image].

After the update of either underlying Linux System or Android system, we, each time we run the bash terminal, we need to update/run `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` path variable. The `bash.bashrc` inside the `/etc` directory script runs everytime we open bash terminal.

Add, at the last line, your `/etc/bash.bashrc` file as below.

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/upg/Android/Sdk
```

Other than this, if you want to update other environmental variables, such as $PATH, you can update that too there in `bash.bashrc` file.

Comment: Sorry, not working. I have it pointing to such a directory and it says it's broken anyway.