# Windows: PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your Android_SDK_Root value [C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local\Android\SDK]!

Tags: android, command-line, android-virtual-device

I have created an AVD on Windows 8.1 and trying to run it through command line but facing below issue.

**Command:** emulator -avd [AVD Path]

**Error:** PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your Android_SDK_Root value [C:\Users[User]\AppData\Local\Android\SDK]!

I have set the Android_SDK_ROOT value to SDK home directory. This works fine if i run emulator through android studio.

Can anyone help this?

Thanks,

Chandresh Parmar

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please follow below step to run AVD

F:\AndroidStudioSetup\sdk>cd tools

F:\AndroidStudioSetup\sdk\tools>emulator -list-avds
Nexus_5_API_24

F:\AndroidStudioSetup\sdk\tools>emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_24

Hax is enabled

Hax ram_size 0x60000000

HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.

Comment: it's not working for me ..till the error is as same as it is

Answer (score 9):

Open your android studio then focus on the toolbar.

Goto tools > SDK manager then

Appearance & Behavior > Systems Settings > Android SDK

Now in the tab copy the Android SDK Location from here [Android SDK Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qK6PT.png)

then goto your environment variables and then set the path along with these variables

1. ANDROID_HOME
2. ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

[Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynqTY.png)

Comment: This works for me! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645178/panic-broken-avd-system-path-check-your-android-sdk-root-value

Comment: @AhmerShahid THIS IS THE ONLY ANSWER THAT WORKED FOR ME. I SEARCHED FOR HOURS..... THANKS!