# Moving Android Virtual Device (AVD) from one computer to another

Tags: android, virtual-machine, virtualization, android-virtual-device

I am trying to clone my AVD to another computer with no much luck. 
I want all the application installed on it will be saved together with the data.

I tried to follow some instructions I found on the web but they don't work for me. 
Simply copying the avd files including changing the ini files simply causing the AVD to load in a 'vanilla' mode where all the apps and data is lost...

Note, that doing so on my computer works so i can save a copy in that manner. I guess there is another configuration somewhere that I am missing but it is not in the avd folder.

any pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: You only need to copy the SD card image used by the virtual machine. Then you need to configure the other AVD  to use that as it's hard drive

Comment: Only the SD card? What about the other img files?

Comment: Can't remember what the names are. Assuming the data you want is on that IMG file, then yes. My main point is that you should only need to move those

Comment: I tried.. from some reason it ignores my img files. I edited the configuration files to inflict the path changes with no luck... I'll try again with a different AVD maybe...

Comment: doesn't work. it seems that from some reason the original folders' path are embedded in the qcow2 files. when i run the emulator from a command line i get messages saying it is searching for files and doesn't find them. the original files paths are listed.... Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, not really. Personally, I still use Genymotion as my emulator, which is just a vmdk file

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found my problem and answer here: [PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645178/panic-broken-avd-system-path-check-your-android-sdk-root-value/44386974#44386974)

apparntly the AVD has hard coded base files in the qemu image files. I had to use the HEX editor to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved same problem by creating same virtual device on same API, run it first time, than copy several ini-files from new AVD to transferred one.