# emulator doesn't accept ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to start an Android emulator on Windows 10, but I keep getting this error message:

```
PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:\Users\tamas\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk]!
```

Yes, I know I have to check the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT variable. Thing is... it's set properly. The above directory is indeed the SDK root, and every part of it is in place.

```
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is E8BA-CBB6

 Directory of c:\Users\tamas\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

07/21/2018  01:21 PM    <DIR>          .
07/21/2018  01:21 PM    <DIR>          ..
07/21/2018  01:17 PM                16 .knownPackages
06/14/2018  12:38 AM    <DIR>          add-ons
06/14/2018  12:21 AM    <DIR>          build-tools
07/21/2018  09:40 AM    <DIR>          emulator
07/19/2018  10:30 PM    <DIR>          extras
06/14/2018  12:39 AM    <DIR>          licenses
06/14/2018  12:25 AM    <DIR>          patcher
06/14/2018  12:21 AM    <DIR>          platform-tools
06/14/2018  12:38 AM    <DIR>          platforms
07/21/2018  12:17 PM    <DIR>          skins
07/19/2018  10:46 PM    <DIR>          sources
07/21/2018  12:18 PM    <DIR>          system-images
07/21/2018  12:54 PM    <DIR>          tools
               2 File(s)             16 bytes
              14 Dir(s)  392,152,141,824 bytes free
```

It just doesn't want to take it. I tried unsetting `System` and `Hidden` attributes, but it didn't help. No amount of tinkering seems to be able to make it work, regardless if I try to launch it from the AVD or command prompt.

Comment: Any help in here? [PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645178/panic-broken-avd-system-path-check-your-android-sdk-root-value)

Answer (score 2):

What version of the **Android SDK tools** do you have? As the API evolves, you must keep them updated or the emulators will eventually fail to start.

You should [update your SDK tools to latest **version 27**](https://www.andreszsogon.com/using-android-8-and-9-emulators-without-android-studio/), then reinstall the SDK System Images, and finally configure your system (HAXM/Hypervisor) according to your processor (Intel/AMD).

Answer (score 2):

A recent update to Android Studio broke this for me too with the identical error message (albeit on a mac).

In my case NVPACK, a software development kit from NVIDIA, was somehow interfering. (The hint was that it overwrote my `$ANDROID_HOME` setting in my `.bashrc` and set a whole bunch of environment variables globally.) Setting `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` was not sufficient to fix the issue.

My solution was to run `NVPACK/uninstall` and the problem was solved.

Comment: I have the same problem with a Windows computer.