# Newly created Android virtual device in Visual Studio doesn't work

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, windows-10

Newly created Android virtual device in Visual Studio doesn't work saying

Device error: PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value

[image]

Variable exists and correct

```
C:\Users\Dmitry
λ echo %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
```

What is it and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to question: [PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645178/panic-broken-avd-system-path-check-your-android-sdk-root-value)

As Oleg Cherr said:

Go to `<user_home>/.android/avd/<avd_name>` and open `config.ini`. Find the `image.sysdir.1` property. It points at the directory inside SDK containing system images. **Make sure that this directory exists and contains files like `build.prop,`system.img`, etc**. If it doesn't, then you have to open the SDK Manager and download system images your AVD requires (see below).