# (MacOS/homebrew) PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value

Tags: macos, android-emulator, homebrew, android-virtual-device

installed:

```
 brew cask install android-sdk
 brew cask install android-platform-tools
 brew cask install intel-haxm
 export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/usr/local/share/android-sdk"
```

created emulator:

```
sdkmanager "system-images;android-27;google_apis;x86"
avdmanager create avd -n default --abi google_apis/x86 -k "system-images;android-27;google_apis;x86" -p ~/.android/avd/default
```

start emulator:

```
emulator -avd default
```

The message:

> PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [/usr/local/share/android-sdk]!

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44386974/1110503) mentions platform/platform-tools folders must be in SDK_ROOT.

```
ls /usr/local/share/android-sdk
```

> emulator      licenses      patcher       system-images tools

What's wrong and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was the missing part:

```
sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-27"
```

That installs the missing parts of SDK. Error message could be better, of course. 
Also not clear if the line below was even needed.

```
brew cask install android-platform-tools
```