# Emulator: PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [F:\android]?

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator

I have the following error when I try to launch my emulator in android studio:

```
Emulator: PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [F:\android]!
```

In Android Studio the sdk location is the following:

[image: This]

Here is the F:\android folder: (Android Studio downloaded the sdk)

[image]

Both ANDROID_HOME and ANDROID_ROOT_SDK is set to this directory.[image]

I have tried almost all the possible solutions here in stackoverflow but they did not work.

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem.
Solution i've found here: [PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645178/panic-broken-avd-system-path-check-your-android-sdk-root-value)

1.I've moved content of my .android folder from C:\Users\MyUser.android to D:\Soft\AvdAndroid

2.Set system variables:

ANDROID_AVD_HOME = D:\Soft\AvdAndroid\avd,

ANDROID_SDK_HOME = D:\Soft\AvdAndroid,

ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = D:\Soft\Android_SDK

After that I've deleted old virtual devices and  created new virtual device (Tools - AVD Manager)

Comment: This worked for me! After some hours of trying other things from other threads. Thank you!

Comment: Worked here too. ANDROID_AVD_HOME defintion did the trick. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes. it works for me on windows 7