# Android Emulator The emulator process for AVD was killed. Windows Intel

Tags: android, android-emulator

The emulators stopped running.
Configuration:
Windows 10, Intel, HAXM Installed, Virtualization ON, GPU software, emulators reinstalled. Immediately after turning on, this error falls (The emulator process for AVD was killed), the emulator does not even appear

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36841461/7746134

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Emulator issues in new versions - The emulator process has terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346232/android-emulator-issues-in-new-versions-the-emulator-process-has-terminated)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

One of the solution is:

Select "Tools" -> "SDK Manager" -> "SDK Tools" tab -> and update to latest Android Emulator version.

[image]

Answer (score 35):

None of the solutions worked for me.
Here are the generic steps to help you find the problem (**windows and macos**):

> WINDOWS

1. Try to find **emulator** folder in **sdk** folder, in my case it is `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator`
2. Open terminal in this folder and call `emulator -list-avds` and see names of emulators, in my case it is `Pixel_2_API_30`
3. Next step try to call this emulator with command `emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_30`
4. Your emulator will start or show an error. In my case I sow this
   [image]
5. I needed to install the missing dll. I go to link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0 and install **Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019** and now all ok!!!

> MAC OS

1. Try to find **emulator** folder in **sdk** folder, in my case it is `/Users/[USER_NAME]/Library/Android/sdk/emulator`
2. Open terminal in this folder and call `emulator -list-avds` and see names of emulators, in my case it is `Pixel_4_API_31`
3. Next step try to call this emulator with command `emulator -avd Pixel_4_API_31`
4. Your emulator will start or show an error. In my case I sow this error
   [image]
5. This helped https://stackoverflow.com/a/45490757/916826

> Warning: Of course, in your case, you may have another error - but you can easily find a solution on the Internet knowing the reason

Comment: better method than solution, nice

Comment: This is a really good answer, because it shows how to diagnose the problem -- also works on Linux, with a different path of course

Comment: didn't work for me, no error message shows.

Comment: What about Linux?

Answer (score 33):

Make sure your machine has enough storage space, sometimes AVD requires up to 10GB or more to start.

Comment: This was the problem for me.

Comment: This one was my issue as well!

Comment: Spent whole day trying to update all to newest possible version, and still was getting error. Until I spotted that there is only 2GB left on C:. I do highly recommend to check if your machine has enough storage space before trying any other solutions.

Comment: This was the problem for me

Comment: Was the solution to my problem too. It's crazy how ambiguous the error message is!

Comment: Yes this was my issue as well, I was done to 2-3gb free on the C:\. They really need to make a better error message for this situation. This happens to me every few weeks and always forget why.

Comment: This was the problem for me, as well. I realized it once I give enough free space on C drive. Even it does not work when there is 8GB of free space. Once I increased it to 11GB, this error disappeared.

Comment: True. You need at least the 10G but it would be better if you have at least 15G because of those crazy updates by Android Studio.

Comment: 8.8 GB free space failed, 10.8 GB free space worked. It is one of the worst error messages (and Google has no excuse of working with software providing no clear error - as they are responsible also for emulator!)

Has anyone already tried to report to google as bug report? (I know that it will be almost certainly ignored)

Answer (score 15):

To debug the exact cause of this issue, On the tabs section of android studio,

click '**Help**',

then '**Show log in explorer**'.

After opening the file, if you see any message like

'**Emulator: cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed
Emulator: cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed** ',

Then follow these four steps

1.Download the **vulkan.dll** file from the internet(Google search for these and you would see sources to download from) or get from any other source.

2.Extract the dll file

3. Place it in **c\Users[your username]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\lib64**.

4.Then **rename** the file to '**vulkan-1.dll**'

Then run your emulator and see it come up

Comment: Thanks, dude. This is the exact solution I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I spent 3 days to resolves this.

Comment: Spent 2 days, tried many ways but none of them worked. Finally, this one solved my problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: dont forget to **wipe data** after this solution

Answer (score 12):

I have same problem as you. Now I resolved it by these steps.

- Open SDK Manager, select "SDK Tools" Tab
- Uncheck box "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)" then "OK"
- Open AVD Manager, try to start emulator and then let it to install HAXM
- Finally, Emulator can be started. I think so HAXM Version is update (old is 7.5.1 and new is 7.5.6).

Comment: I solved the same issue by installing Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) in the SDK Manager. It wasn't installed before.

Comment: There is no HAXM in the SDK Tools tab. Only in the SDK Updates Sites tab but that cannot be changed.

Answer (score 9):

Uncheck "Launch in a tool window" from File-> Settings -> emulator
Should work.

Answer (score 8):

I want to make a contribution to this thread, I have tried many of the possible solutions that I have found on the net, including the one that is now marked as Solution and I have not managed to solve the problem until I have modified the SDK path to match the ones System variables

[image]
[image]

Comment: You are my savior @rafa_pe

Answer (score 7):

Just make sure you have enough disk space on your machine, I freed up space and didn't have to do any of the steps mentioned above.

Answer (score 6):

I had same issue.

I changed ANDROID_HOME path on environment variables.

And then I copied 'avd' folder, which emulator installed in into 'sdk' folder(ANDROID_HOME path).

*** You can find 'avd' folder by clicking 'Show on Disk' in AVD manger.

I restarted the emulator and then it is running well now.

Comment: what OS is this solution for?

Comment: My Solution is for Windows system.

Answer (score 4):

Same issue here, resolved it by uninstalling all the unused SDKs to free some disk space

=> uncheck them in **SDK Manager** then **Apply**, and **Finish** when the uninstallation process is done, finally restart your Android Studio, it should be ok

Check all the solutions proposed in this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64469129/14517970

Answer (score 4):

For me, it happened to be that my machine was out of disk space. However, I was able to verify this by running the emulator from the command line in order to get a more detailed error message:

```sh
$ emulator -list-avds
Pixel_3_API_29
Pixel_3_API_30
Pixel_5_API_30_R_

$ emulator -avd Pixel_3_API_29
emulator: Android emulator version 30.4.1.0 (build_id 7075546) (CL:N/A)
emulator: ERROR: Not enough disk space to run AVD 'Pixel_3_API_29'. Exiting...
```

Freeing disk space worked. Note, a great way to free up lots of space is to open Android Virtual Device Manager and select `wipe data`. For me, this cleared 8 GB just with one emulator that I hadn't used in a long while and was fine to reset.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are many reasons why the emulator process can quit. This dialog unfortunately provides this misleading message with no further details.

If you have [Android SDK Command-line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61155485/5763764) installed, run emulator from the command line to see what's happening.

```sh
emulator -list-avds   # get available AVD names
emulator @<avd-name>  # try to start emulator
```

Error messages will follow. In my case it was insufficient disk space.

Comment: And if anyone wondering how to use the command line tools, refer [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line#tools-emulator)

Answer (score 2):

Same issue occurred with me multiple time. Try following points hope it help you.

1. File-> invalidate Cache/ Restart.
2. File-> Settings -> Tools -> Emulator -> Now uncheck(Launch in a tool window)
3. AVD Manager -> more option -> show on disk -> Now delete(hardware-qemu.ini.lock) and run again.

Answer (score 2):

If updating doesn't work for you try opening the emulator with command line for ubuntu

> locate emulator location in Terminal (cd Home/Android/Sdk/emulator).

> run this command emulator -avd EMULATOR_NAME

This will open the emulator or will tell the actual error that you can fix. in my case the problem was my system has low space left than the required for emulator (6GB < 8GB)

Comment: Hey, what do you mean by emulator_name? Using the name I set in AVD tells me ERROR: can't find the emulator executable. Edit: ah, that was the actual error. I thought that was an error because I entered the EMULATOR_NAME part wrong or something.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is for windows but I share my solution in case anyone with **Ubuntu** is here.

#### What happened:

In my case that happened when I changed my machine completely but keep my storage device. In my old storage device I had Ubuntu 20.04, android studio 4.1.2 and I was trying to run a pixel 4 android Q emulator. Both old device and new device were Intel x86.

When I tried to open my emulator for the first time I faced this error.

#### Solution:

I deleted the android image from tools > SDK Manager > SDK platforms, by unchecking the android image, and then install it again. Obviously it downloads it again. Then I deleted my old AVD and create a new one and every thing start working.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check that Android Emulator is properly installed or not. If there an update available for emulator then it should be updated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, then I tried multiple things to fix that but no luck, then I chose a different system image and now it works.

currently, I have (PIE android 9.0)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you just created the emulator and it has never been run before, you need to run it as a stand-alone window for the first time, then you can run it in a tool window (in the Android studio window).
To run the emulator as standalone app:

- In the android studio settings go to tools>Emulator and make sure that "Launch in a tool window" is disabled before running the project.
- Or close the project and start the emulator
- Or run this command line `emulator -avd {your virtual device name here}`  [more info](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#starting)

Answer (score 0):

I had this error too. The issue was my 'avd' folder creating the image and 'avd' folder when trying to launch the android emulator were pointing to two different places.

**The solution:**

step 1: create an environment variable to redirect both paths back to the same place
[image]

step 2: restart Android studio

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else works, what solved it for me was:

Tools > SDK Manager > Reinstall Android emulator and HAXM

Answer (score 0):

If the emulator was already working and you get into this error, then the emulator executable crashed, but the process is still running.

Find these processes with your process explorer and kill them. They should look similar like

- emulator.exe
- qemu-system-x86_64.exe

[image: Process Explorer Screenshot]

Afterwards go to your AVD directory where your device is located and delete `multiinstance.lock` file. Restart Android Studio, and launch the device in the AVD manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a 7th Generation Intel® Core™ i7 processor, there is a reported bug with Intel HAXM.
The only way that I manage to run the emulator is on the command-line by turning off hardware acceleration and the AVD was very **slow**.
Here is how:

To get the list of installed AVDs (assuming your default emulator path is as follows)

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -list-avds
```

Start an AVD (*Nexus_5X_API_25* of example) with hardware acceleration off

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5X_API_25 -accel off
```

You can add the `-verbose -show-kernel` options to get detailed info.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me. This did:

I followed the steps mentioned in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66396571/13120177), but it didn't show any errors. It also said to "Update emulator because it's outdated", although my emulator was already up-to-date. I restarted Studio & ran the AVD from AVD manager and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue on my fresh installed Linux Mint with Nvidia GPU. The problem was solved after the GPU driver installed.

Go to "Driver Manager" to see if there is driver available.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to come to read on my solution which is after 25 Answers.
Still I suggest this solution which helped me as non others helped:

1. Use command in cmd: cd C:<SDK-Path>\Android\Sdk\emulator>emulator -list-avds
2. List all emulator using:
   emulator -list-avds
3. Run emulator using: emulator @Your-Emulator-Name
4. This will show you error on why emulator is not able to launch.
5. For me it was:
   handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
   cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed
6. Downlaod vulkan-1.dll file by googling
7. Place this file in c:\Windows\System32
8. Launch Emulator again
   Viola!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, Intel, Android Studio 2020.3.1 Patch 4 in

**Tools** > **AVD Manager** > **Create virtual device**
**Phone** > **Pixel XL** > **Next**
On **System Image** > **x86 Images** tab > **API 32** > **Next**

Let the image download and finish.

Basically I choose from x86_64 Images.

Answer (score -1):

Mine was caused by lack of space on my primary Hard Drive on my PC. Once I had at least 4 GB the error cleared.