# Android Avd is getting killed

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

I am getting an error that is saying The emulator process was killed and I don't know how to solve that. I am thinking that I can change the location of the avd folder since my C folder is out of storage. But I don't know how to do that, please help me I am a sixth grader.

Comment: this link will help you out https://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/clients/761-move-android-studio-avd-folder-to-a-new-location

Comment: You can follow this link however, this type of question is already answered.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63317727/android-emulator-the-emulator-process-for-avd-was-killed-windows-intel