# Received the error "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_3_API_30 was killed" on trying to run a newly created virtual device inside Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, avd-manager, virtual-device-manager

Just installed Android Studio. Verified all the files are updated. Tried to add

Received the error "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_3_API_30 was killed" on trying to run a newly created virtual device inside Android Studio

Attempts made:

---

1. checked for updates. Kotlin plugin update and Android Emulator updates were done, which were observed pending.
2. tried to change the Graphics from "Automatic" to "Software" but the drop down was non-editable

Log data:

---

Name: Pixel_3_API_30

CPU/ABI: Google Play Intel Atom (x86)

Path: C:\Users\vysakh.android\avd\Pixel_3_API_30.avd

Target: google_apis_playstore [Google Play] (API level 30)

Skin: pixel_3

SD Card: 512M

fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile:

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: pixel_3

hw.lcd.width: 1080

hw.initialOrientation: Portrait

image.androidVersion.api: 30

tag.id: google_apis_playstore

hw.mainKeys: no

hw.camera.front: emulated

avd.ini.displayname: Pixel 3 API 30

hw.gpu.mode: auto

hw.ramSize: 1536

PlayStore.enabled: true

fastboot.forceColdBoot: no

hw.cpu.ncore: 4

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

hw.dPad: no

hw.lcd.height: 2160

vm.heapSize: 256

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.gps: yes

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-30\google_apis_playstore\x86\

showDeviceFrame: yes

hw.camera.back: emulated

AvdId: Pixel_3_API_30

hw.lcd.density: 440

hw.arc: false

hw.device.hash2: MD5:8a60718609e0741c7c0cc225f49c5590

fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot: no

fastboot.forceFastBoot: yes

hw.trackBall: no

hw.battery: yes

hw.sdCard: yes

tag.display: Google Play

runtime.network.latency: none

disk.dataPartition.size: 2G

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes

Thanks and regards,
Vysakh Suresh

Answer (score 1):

I had this type of issue with emulator when my main disk where sits the emulator have less than 2gb free space. I cant place comments. So just check the disk space on you OS drive. On default emulator will save images in user direcroty.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. forgot to mention the attempt too. Had 7 Gb of free space in C drive (no other partitions are there in system). Made it 11.4 GB ad tried again. But was observantly giving same concern.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66396571/16266470 try to  get more info on error

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Installed the dll files as per alerted in the command line. Installed,
glib-2-vs11.dll
Qt5CoreAndroidEmu.dll
Qt5WidgetsAndroidEmu.dll
Qt5guiAndroidEmu.dll
libGLEsv2.dll
Qt5QmlAndroidEmu.dll
But now it asks for Qt5NetworkAndroidEmu.dll which i couldnt find anywhere

Comment: https://internetaccessmonitor.ru/dll/qt5network.dll but scan it with antivirus software

Comment: Thanks for the reply. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66396571/16266470 was helpful. now the dll errors are no longer coming. When I execute the command "emulator -avd Pixel_3_API_30" my emulator is opening. but from Android Studio, it is still giving error "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_3_API_30 was killed". Actually, I was studying flutter. Will it be fine having the emulator opened liked this rather than from the AVD Manager.

Comment: @VysakhSuresh try to reinstall "Android emulator" from tools and same for "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator". Do you have more than one "Android SDK" installed on you computer? And check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62340495/16266470

Comment: Check if installing/reinstalling `Intel HAXM` helps.