# Why I can't run android simulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, simulator

I have installed the new version of Android Studio. But when I click AVD Manager. I have some errors.

The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_30 has terminated.
[image: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_30 has terminated.]

I have found some solutions but they can't work for me. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is some the case of the same error too,
try to took a look this link down here

[Android Emulator Issues in new versions - The emulator process has terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346232/android-emulator-issues-in-new-versions-the-emulator-process-has-terminated)

and this too

[Android Emulator The emulator process for AVD was killed. Windows Intel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63317727/android-emulator-the-emulator-process-for-avd-was-killed-windows-intel)

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys here is the solution that worked for me in the android studio bumblebee
here are the steps how I solved this error:
goto->controlPanel in search bar->Programs->turn windows features on or off->tick the box with "virtual machine platform" or "Hyper V"
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4hE8rE-vrjg)

Above is the link for a youtube video that helped me to solve the error.