# How to test Google Maps v2 on Android emulator API level 17?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator, google-play-services

I am building an Android app that has Google Maps v2. The map requires the Google Play services. I want to test the app in the emulator running API level 17 (Android 4.2.2).

I have downloaded the **Google API** package from the SDK manager. Then I created a virtual device for it. When I start the emulator I am presented with the following error.

> Cannot launch AVD in emulator. Output: emulator: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!! Emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined.

What should I do to test Google Maps v2 in Android 4.2.2 emulator?

[image]

My virtual device configuration:

[image]

Comment: show your emulator configuration

Comment: @VivekMishra updated the question.

Comment: you should use images with google api's to test google services

Comment: What is the value defined for  `sdk.dir` of `local.properties`?

Comment: @VivekMishra, which of the images should I include (see my SDK manager screenshot)?

Comment: google api'sAndroid 17

Comment: @VivekMishra but that is what I used to create the emulator. It was the only option as I have not downloaded any other images.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712605/emulator-error-this-avds-configuration-is-missing-a-kernel-file check this link

Comment: @VivekMishra, yes I saw this question, it does not help me unfortunately. But thanks.

Comment: did emulator using another android version run??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99662/discussion-between-evgenii-and-vivek-mishra).

Answer (score 1):

For sdk 17, you need to download intel x86 Atom System Image with the Google APIs (as you have)

[image]

Then Choose x86 Android and create it. It works for me, but will not show maps due to lack of internet connection.

[image]

For adk 20 and higher:
When you first select create virtual device, you need to pick an image with the google apis.

[image]

So this is the step before the screen shot you've shown.

Comment: I can not see images named like that, see my SDK manager screenshot. The question was specifically about API Level 17, not 21.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I am launching the x86 Atom emulator. On launch the app shows the button "Get Google Play Services". I guess it does not have them installed. When I tap the button the app crashes with following exception `No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms`.

Comment: The x86 Atom emulator does not have Google Play Services installed. Google Play Services are not listed in Settings > Apps either.