# Cannot launch AVD in emulator. ?android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-bundle

my emulator is not runnnig and gives the error in image below

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wexwy.png)

and test at run window

> C:\Users\Wahlah\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe
>   -netdelay gprs -netspeed full -avd Nexus_4_API_21
>          This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual   way.
>          Please contact the application's support team for more information.
>          terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
>          what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid

and second error exist is this image

[ERROR 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pI5PO.png)

Comment: windows platform 64bit

Comment: Did you solve it? If so, please add an answer here, or edit the question with an update. I'm having the exact same problem and can't find any information about it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem with the same logged warnings and errors (and the alert as well).

Although from the first logged line (`C:\...emulator.exe`) it looked like the tools did find the emulator - my problem was resolved only after I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712605/emulator-error-this-avds-configuration-is-missing-a-kernel-file/10775330#10775330), and changed the `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` environment variable (which pointed to a folder above the sdk instead to the sdk's folder itself).

So I changed it from

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android
```

to

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

and... voila! The emulator is running properly.

I should note that I'm working on Windows and from the question it looks like AIR TRAVELS was as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it by selecting Cold Boot from the Tools > Android > AVD Manager > Edit > Show Advanced > Boot option from Quick Boot to Cold Boot.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this error, need configure the device again. Download all the necessary libraries through the SDK manager.

Comment: did but `Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: emulator.exe
  Application Version: 0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp: 00000000
  Fault Module Name: emulator.exe`

Comment: Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.