# No USB devices or running emulators detected in android studio 2.2.3

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

I have a problem with the running of anny app want to run it in android
    studio, if i click on the button of RUN just show up to me that message:

> No USB devices or running emulators detected.

And when i click on "Ok" show up that note:

> minSdk(API 16) > deviceSdk(API 14).

See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKQTa.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if i click on the button of RUN just show up to me that message: No
>   USB devices or running emulators detected.

you are not running any emulators and you did not connected any physical  device for USB debugging (see [Run Apps on a Hardware Device](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html)).

> And when i click on "Ok" show up that note: minSdk(API 16) >
>   deviceSdk(API 14).

The emulator is running Android API **14** and your project's `minSDK` is **16** so your project will not run on devices/emulators < your project's `minSDK` (read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels))

---

So either change your `minSDK` to 14 (if this is OK) or test on an device/emulator with SDK >= 16.

Comment: Thank you, but i want not use a physical device..So what should i do?

Comment: @saidbous as I mentioned, either change your `minSDK` to 14 (if this is OK) or test on an emulator with SDK >= 16 (create a new emulator with SDK >=16  )

Comment: @saidbous see [Changing API level Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465049/changing-api-level-android-studio) if you want to change your minSDK

Comment: After i create an other device with API 16...show up to me that msg: "Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
                Output:
        emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! Please ensure the file "kernel-qemu" is in the same location as your system image.
        emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined
        start=(Button)findViewById(R.id.startb);"

Comment: @saidbous see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712605/emulator-error-this-avds-configuration-is-missing-a-kernel-file) it might help you and you can always post a new question. good luck