# “kernel-qemu” is missing. - AVD Manager

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-emulator, virtualization, android-virtual-device

I am trying to start a virtual device with the AVD Manager and I noted that the problem occurs with devices with Androids OS olders than Android 6.0 (API 23).

I'm working with Xamarin.Android C# (Visual Studio) and the device that I need to start is one with Android 8.1 (API 27 Intel Atom x86) but when I try to start it the error message appears: "**kernel-qemu**".

Error:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'Ocho'
    emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing to kernel file! Please ensure the file "kernel-qemu" is in the same location as your system image.
    emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is defined (C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Android \ android-sdk \) but can not find kernel file in C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Android \ android-sdk \\ system-images \ sub directories
```

I checked the folder where it should be and there is only one file named "**kernel-ranchu-64**", I've already tried things like renaming the "ranchu" to "qemu" but **it does not work**.

I do not know what else to try.
Does anyone have that **kernel-qemu file** that I need to run the emulator?

[qemu-Error-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1Tfp.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulator error: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712605/emulator-error-this-avds-configuration-is-missing-a-kernel-file)

Comment: I already check that question and many others like it, but none of those answers have worked for me. They also mentioned Eclipse or some other program configurations and that’s not my case either.

Comment: I fixed this by using a virtual device with Android 9.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by using a virtual device with Android 9.0.
Also, another option is to use Genymotion.

Answer (score 6):

IN Folder 'system-images'

find the files named : kernel-XXXXX

change the names to  kernel-qemu

that works.

Comment: It worked for me to copy / rename 'kernel-ranchu' to 'kernel-qemu' found deep in 'system-images'.