# Missing a kernel file when running Android emulator

Tags: flutter, android-emulator

when I run my emulator this error appear

```
INFO | Android emulator version 33.1.24.0 (build_id 11237101) (CL:N/A) 
INFO | Found systemPath C:\Users\madeh\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-11\images\
ERROR | This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! Please ensure the file "kernel-ranchu" is in the same location as your system image. 
ERROR | ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined
INFO | Storing crashdata in: , detection is enabled for process: 20372
INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
```

I created a new AVD but it did not work

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712605/emulator-error-this-avds-configuration-is-missing-a-kernel-file